# Can't empty trash after external drive was unplugged

Tags: ntfs, delete, trash

I've taken an USB hard drive of my teacher and now I've returned it him back. It was NTFS and I deleted some files there. Now my Trash icon is still full, while the trash is empty. How to make the icon empty and correct.
I've always tried following commands

```
sudo rm -rf /media/*
sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*
```

But there is still no result

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo nautilus .local/share/Trash/files` then delete the contents.